# Do these FAQ questions need to be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, support, meta-faq

I am referring to [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)
The first question contains some answers that repeat what already said from other answers. Rather than a FAQ seems a discussion where everybody gives their own opinion.
The second question, differently from what its title would make think, is a request from Jeff Atwood to report which HTML tags should be allowed, where the question lists the tags that were allowed.

In the first case, some of the answers should probably be merged, while in the second case, the question should be rewritten to ask which HTML tags are allowed, and an answer reporting the HTML tags effectively supported should be added to replace the existing ones.

Do these FAQ questions need to be cleaned up?

Comment: So says Frank Brandon Nelson